# Which cloud infra should I use for a Nodejs API with Redis as a db

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, cloud

Giving a little bit of background first, I'm building a nodejs api which serves data stored in a Redis database. I also have a worker with runs every day scheduled by a node cronjob. Currently, both the worker and the api are on the same application. I'm using docker in my local development environment, so I have a `docker-compose` which I use to spin up the redis db and also a dockerfile for the node app.

I'm planning on deploying this to some cloud provider. So, which Cloud Provider would be the best giving the background above?

I did some research already, mostly on Google Cloud products, and found that Cloud Run and Memorystore would be a good choice. Though, Memorystore does not have a free tier as of my research, and that was a drawback for me at least for now.

Therefore, can you give me some suggestion on a cloud service provider that I can use, mainly for the redis db that has a good free tier?

Or do you have another suggestion on how to use such services (node api and redis) in the cloud?

PS: I might rewrite the app to use firebase as the storage, but I was wanting to use redis for its speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Run with Memorystore is good to go.

But if you want using it for free, you can apply a GCP or AWS account and using GCE or EC2 Free Tier within one year, then running both Node.js app and Redis service on the machine.

Firebase might not be a good choice if you want to scale up in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @eason 
I'll take a look at EC2 and GCE, then, and see how it is to deploy on both services. 
Thanks again!